# How to get value from row in kivymd datatable using on_row_press() method

Tags: python, datatable, kivymd

I'm trying to get data from the row which I will press. But I didn't get any related data which is in my table.
**Here is my code**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen =Screen()
        table = MDDataTable(
            column_data=[('roll no',dp(15)),
                         ('name',dp(30))],
            row_data=[(1,'Hasib'),
                      (2,'shihab')])
        table.bind(on_row_press=self.row_press)
        screen.add_widget(table)
        return screen

    def row_press(self,instance_table,instance_row):
       print(instance_row)

Example().run()
```

I got this-
<kivymd.uix.datatables.datatables.CellRow object at 0x0000020A467307B0>

If I press any I wanted to get the roll and name.
I read the kivymd docs but I didn't get my answer
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This may help, if you use "print(instance_row.text)" you will get the text for that specific column and row.

Answer (score 0):

`index` is index of cell in the table.
Divide by number of rows to get `row_data` index

```py
ind = instance_row.index // 2 # number of rows 
row_data = instance_table.row_data[ind]
```